# Multiple measures in crosstab - Cognos 8

Tags: percentage, crosstab, cognos

Is it possible to add more than one measure in a single crosstab?

I have a crosstab in which rows represent departments and columns represent gender. It is possible to display counts and percentages?

I am reporting from relational data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can add multiple measures to your crosstab by nesting them in either rows or columns.
In your example, nest Counts and Percentages under Departments row or Gender Column.

Given below is an example of displaying two measures Revenue and Quantity in a crosstab. 
[image]

The result looks like this:
[image]

Please refer to IBM Infocenter for more details on nested Crosstab. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp